# PHP within echo

Tags: php, mysql

```
 echo '<div class"Match-box" align="center">'.$Voornaam_array[$n]. '<br>' .$Tweedenaam_array[$n]. '<br>' .$Achternaam_array[$n]. 
         '<br><br><a href="INSERT LINK TO DETERMINED PLACE" class="Match-button">'.$Voornaam_array[$n].' toevoegen aan matches<a><br><br></div>' ;
```

So this is my php code snippet, in which I want the link to be determined by php code(I want to run a query between the ""). The arrays displayed only contain text.

How can I make this working?

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks in advance,

Comment: do you have any PHP knowledge at all?

Comment: Same way as you do everything else: `... <a href="' . $determinedLink . '" ...`

Comment: run query on link? i dont understand

Comment: I'm sorry but I am totally new to this. I just wanted some help. I read about jumping in and out of the echo but I fear my div will be(may be incredibly stupid) split up.

Comment: Don't worry about people being mean @Evochrome some people are just rude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do different things when in this situation but here is one.

```
'<br><br><a href="'. $var .'" class="Match-button">'
```